# Return the largest several numbers as a list of a data frame in r

Tags: r, function

I have dataset call `df`, like this:

```
Title Time   Gross
a     12/21   2313
b     11/12   1298
c     4/09    10034
d     09/30   3498
e     10/31   2375
y     01/10   8492
```

I want write a function, return the `Title` and `Gross` of 3 entries with largest `Gross`.
I tried like this:

```
names.revenues <- function(num, data){
  i = 1
  for(i in 1:num){
    inds = which.max(data$Gross)
    names[i] = data$Title[inds]
    revenues[i] = data$Gross[inds]
    data = data[-inds, ]
    i = i + 1
  }
  return(list(names = names, revenues = revenues))
}
names.revenues(3, df)
```

But this doesn't work, please give me a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Would you please provide an example dataset, so that you have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I changed the question, thanks.

Comment: `head(df[order(-df$Gross),], 3)` ?  Or using `data.table` maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[order(-Gross)][1:3]`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I mean, if I want to write a function like this. I could get any number of this. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has some mistakes, here's a possible working version:

```
names.revenues <- function(num, data){
  # initialize names and revenues with NAs
  names <- rep.int(NA,num)
  revenues <- rep.int(NA,num)

  for(i in 1:num){
    inds = which.max(data$Gross)
    names[i] = data$Title[inds]
    revenues[i] = data$Gross[inds]
    data = data[-inds, ]
  }
  return(list(names = names, revenues = revenues))
}
```

Example :

```
df <- data.frame(Title=letters[1:10],
                 Time=format(format='%m/%d',Sys.Date()+1:10),
                 Gross=c(10,200,40,500,70,500,20,300,10,50),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# > df
#    Title  Time Gross
# 1      a 10/30    10
# 2      b 10/31   200
# 3      c 11/01    40
# 4      d 11/02   500
# 5      e 11/03    70
# 6      f 11/04   500
# 7      g 11/05    20
# 8      h 11/06   300
# 9      i 11/07    10
# 10     j 11/08    50

res1 <- names.revenues(5, df)
# > res 1
# $names
# [1] "d" "f" "h" "b" "e"
# 
# $revenues
# [1] 500 500 300 200  70
```

But is possible to obtain basically the same result with this (more efficient) one-liner :

```
res2 <- head(df[order(df$Gross,decreasing=TRUE),],5)
# > res2
#   Title  Time Gross
# 4     d 11/02   500
# 6     f 11/04   500
# 8     h 11/06   300
# 2     b 10/31   200
# 5     e 11/03    70
```

Comment: So, I need to create vector for names and revenues before I put sth. in, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case I preallocated it since I know in advance the length of the vector, but in other cases you can initialize to `NULL` then append to it e.g. `v <- NULL` then `v <- c(v, value2append)`

Comment: Can I use, names <- c(length = num) to create a empty vector?

Comment: No, an empty vector (i.e. a vector with zero elements) of numbers is `v <- numeric()`. To preallocate a vector of `num` elements you need to initialize all values to something e.g. `NA`, `0` etc.

Comment: BTW, you should be careful using vector concatenation in a loop since is not really efficient when performed a lot of times (because every time the old vector is destroyed, a new bigger one is created and the old values copied in it). You should use vectorized operations (like the one-liner above)  whenever is possible since are way more efficient in R.

Comment: I have another question? could you help me ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93741/discussion-between-white-big-and-digemall).